# how to change video file default format in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, video, mp4

Whenever I import a video (mp4) to android studio it defaults to text code format. How can I fix this?

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efl1e.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvmli.png)

I tried to override file format but could not find the suitable format.

Comment: This would be better asked in https://superuser.com/questions This is for programing questions.   Take the [tour] and then see how to ask a question [ask].